# Formula Conditional Formatting between 2 sheets and multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting based on values in another sheet.

For example:

Sheet one needs the conditional formatting applied. If Sheet 2, says `F` then the corresponding cell on Sheet 1 should highlight red.

So in this case, cells `A1` & `B3` on Sheet 1 should be highlighted in red. I selected cells `$A$1:$B$3` on SHEET 1 and used Conditional formatting's formula and entered

```
='Sheet2!$A$1=F
```

and then chose red as the highlight color. But it didn't work. :(

SHEET 1

```
     Col A      Col B
1    Dog        House
2    Cat        Pond
3    Fish       Pond
```

SHEET 2

```
     Col A      Col B
1      F             T
2      T             T
3      T             F
```

Comment: You were close.  the reference need to be relative and the `F` needs to be inside quotes. `='Sheet2!A1="F"`

Comment: And close the `'` so it's `='Sheet2'!A1="F"`

Comment: Oh man! thank you so much! I was trying everything for the last 3 hours. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by chris neilsen: ='Sheet2'!A1="F"